# wp_schedule_event not working

Tags: post-meta

I 'm going to create a sheduled update_post_meta and for some uknown reason the function is never fired. Below is the code:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'scheduled_upm');

function scheduled_upm() {

    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'do_this_every_hour');

}


add_action( 'do_this_every_hour','do_this_every_hour' );

function do_this_every_hour() {


update_post_meta('3197', 'meta_key', '8');


}
```

The normal (as far as I can understand), is that  do_this_every_hour function, will run immediately and after this, it will run every hour.

Am I wrong somewhere?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Your are right: "`do_this_every_hour` function, will run immediately and after this, it will run every hour." I think that you don't know what "after this" means. In your code "after this" means after save a post (any post). Your code are registering a new schedule even each time a post is saved, I really think you don't want this; you can end up with tons of events running hourly.

Comment: Yes you are right, but even this way, the function is never fired. I 've also tried 'wp'.

Comment: How do you know it is not fired? You are update a meta key with a fixed value for a the same post every time, so you can see any change in the post meta. Do you have debug information? Also, although this doesn't explain why it is not fired, you must know that schedule events should be registered only once; best to do at activation of plugin. Not `wp`, `init`, `save_post` or any other action hook. The schedule event should be unregistered at deactivation of the plugin.

Comment: This function is just a test, the post id will be changing dynamically. I know that the action is not fired because the meta value never changes to "8" (I' ve put another value manualy). However the  hook is registered at db 'cron' for like 4 times on 1 save_post, and the data is serialized. I really dont know how the db cron field should be.

Comment: By the way I just mentioned something... My site is not on an public domain name and its just running on my server. I used WP Control to see what happens and the job was entered normaly... How ever it could not fire it with the following error:  

There was a problem spawning a call to the WP-Cron system on your site. This means WP-Cron jobs on your site may not work. The problem was:
Couldn't resolve host 'asite.com'

Comment: Ok I think its solved... For some reason wp_cron is not working without the right dns records. So i wont search for it further... I ll just get the domain name and I ll set it up. Thank you all.

Comment: That is what I was to tell you. WP Cron is not like a cron configured in the server; WP Cron works through HTTP request.